# What factors determine the DA(DH) and RVR/VIS of an ILS approach？

Tags: ils, visibility, procedure-design

Look at the jeppesen chart of “VCBI-ILS Z Rwy 04 ”.
why the DAs are more than 200+RwyElev,and RVRs are more than 550m,
What factors determine the DA(DH) and RVR/VIS of an ILS approach？